# Gradle Checkstyle plugin compatibility with google checkstyle

Tags: gradle, checkstyle

I've installed the google-java-format plugin and placed the following checkstyle in config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml:

https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'checkstyle'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

So, when I run the task checkstyleMain, The following error message appears:

```
Document root element "code_scheme", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Google [Checkstyle](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) and Google [code-style](https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml) are slightly different, and have different formats. That's why you are getting the error message.

Judging by your question, I suppose you want to configure the IntelliJ code style plugin.

You can download the codestyle xml from [here](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml). Then open IntelliJ, go to `File → Settings → Editor → Code Style`. Click on the gear icon with a tooltip which says `Show Scheme Actions` and then select `Import Scheme` -> `IntelliJ IDEA code style XML`. Select the file which you downloaded. If there is a popup window which opens, ensure you tick the `Current scheme`.

More details mentioned [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/dev-intellij.html#_code_style_settings)